# CardView - ViewPager - ListView - CoordinatorLayout - Animation and OpenGl crash

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a ViewPager which use fragments and each fragment displays a list.
When the list displays CardView I obtain the strange but consistent exception each time I scroll the viewPager out from that fragment:

```
03-08 17:19:32.129 13975-13990/? A/OpenGLRenderer: Error: Spot pair overflow!!! used 57, total 54
03-08 17:19:32.129 13975-13990/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13990 (hwuiTask1)
03-08 17:19:32.232 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-08 17:19:32.232 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0.1/MMB29Q/2480792:user/release-keys'
03-08 17:19:32.232 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'rev_1.0'
03-08 17:19:32.232 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
03-08 17:19:32.233 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13975, tid: 13990, name: hwuiTask1  >>> com.android2ee.recyclerview <<<
03-08 17:19:32.233 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
03-08 17:19:32.254 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Error: Spot pair overflow!!! used 57, total 54'
03-08 17:19:32.255 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000036a6  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000000
03-08 17:19:32.255 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
03-08 17:19:32.255 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   000000000000003f  x10  0000007f92bbde0c  x11  0000007f92bbde48
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007f92bbdd20  x13  000000000000002f  x14  0000007f92bbdef8  x15  0000000000000000
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f9c0fd568  x17  0000007f9c09013c  x18  0000007f9c481550  x19  0000007f92bbf500
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f92bbf440  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000000000000006  x23  0000000000000039
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x24  000000000000000c  x25  0000000000000039  x26  0000007f92bfc160  x27  0000007f92bbe740
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000039  x29  0000007f92bbddb0  x30  0000007f9c08d8d8
03-08 17:19:32.256 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f92bbddb0  pc   0000007f9c090144  pstate 0000000020000000
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000006a144  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000000678d4  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000023838  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001dfd8  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000000d024  /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+236)
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000006e800  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.264 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000000743a4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000000000007578c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000006e514  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000076fd0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000000000002c24c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000001579c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+208)
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000008eb30  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+96)
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000000014fec  /system/lib64/libutils.so
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000000000066d24  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+52)
03-08 17:19:32.265 3654-3654/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 000000000001eb84  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
03-08 17:19:32.456 4853-14040/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android2ee.recyclerview/.CoordinatorActivity
03-08 17:19:32.456 3654-3654/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
03-08 17:19:32.493 4853-6914/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 10
03-08 17:19:32.493 4853-6933/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{570ab76 u0 com.android2ee.recyclerview/com.android2ee.recyclerview.CoordinatorActivity}
03-08 17:19:32.501 3667-3667/? I/Zygote: Process 13975 exited due to signal (6)
03-08 17:19:32.535 4853-7048/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.android2ee.recyclerview (pid 13975) has died
```

I found two ways to avoid the problem (look for //TODO uncomment that line and the opengl bug disappears in the project):
The first one is to disable animation on the viewPager (no ViewPager.PageTransformer)
The second way to avoid that is to stop using CardView....

The project is on Github :https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/Animation, it's the module RecyclerView that generates the crash.
https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/Animation/tree/master/recyclerview/src/main/java/com/android2ee/recyclerview
 There is no specific code in that project in fact.

```
public class CardViewRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
/***********************************************************
 * Attributes
 **********************************************************/
private ArrayList<Human> humans;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
/***********************************************************
 *  TezmpVariables
 *********************************************************/
private View tNewView;
private ViewHolder tViewHolder;
private Human human;
/***********************************************************
 * Constructor
 **********************************************************/
public CardViewRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Human> dataSet, Context ctx){
    humans=dataSet;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}


/**    Create the new View and clue it with the return ViewHolder *
 * @param parent   The ViewGroup into which the new View will be added after it is bound to
 *                 an adapter position.
 * @param viewType The view type of the new View.
 * @return A new ViewHolder that holds a View of the given view type.
 * @see #getItemViewType(int)
 * @see #onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int)
 */
@Override
public CardViewRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   // Log.e("RecyclerViewAdapter"," onCreateViewHolder viewtype="+viewType);
    if(viewType==0){
        tNewView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_cardview_item,parent,false);
    }else{
        tNewView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_cardview_item_odd,parent,false);
    }
    tViewHolder=new ViewHolder(tNewView);
    return tViewHolder;
}

/**    Update the View holds by the ViewHolder gave *
 * @param holder   The ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the
 *                 item at the given position in the data set.
 * @param position The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    human=humans.get(position);
    holder.getTxvName().setText(human.getName());
    holder.getTxvFirstName().setText(human.getFirstName());
    holder.getTxvMessage().setText(human.getMessage());
    holder.position=position;
}

/**
 * Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
 *
 * @return The total number of items in this adapter.
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return humans.size();
}

/**
 * Return the view type of the item at <code>position</code> for the purposes
 * of view recycling.
 * <p/>
 * <p>The default implementation of this method returns 0, making the assumption of
 * a single view type for the adapter. Unlike ListView adapters, types need not
 * be contiguous. Consider using id resources to uniquely identify item view types.
 *
 * @param position position to query
 * @return integer value identifying the type of the view needed to represent the item at
 * <code>position</code>. Type codes need not be contiguous.
 */
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    human=humans.get(position);
   // Log.e("RecyclerViewAdapter"," onCreateViewHolder human.getFirstName()="+human.getFirstName());
    if(human.getFirstName().equals("Jeanne")){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

/***********************************************************
 * ViewHolder pattern
 **********************************************************/
public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txvName=null;
    TextView txvFirstName=null;
    TextView txvMessage=null;
    View.OnClickListener clickListener;
    int position;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txvName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txvName);
        txvFirstName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txvFirstName);
        txvMessage= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txvMessage);
        clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeTxvMessageVisibilityState();
            }
        };
        itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }

    public TextView getTxvFirstName() {
        return txvFirstName;
    }

    public TextView getTxvMessage() {
        return txvMessage;
    }

    public TextView getTxvName() {
        return txvName;
    }
    public void changeTxvMessageVisibilityState(){
        if(txvMessage.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            txvMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            txvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The ViewPager.PageTransformer

```
public class MyPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        /****************************************************************************************
 * ViewPager.PageTransformer
     *****************************************************************************************/
public MyPageTransformer() {
}

RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    //Only the main layout is passed here/
    myRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    if(position<0.1&&position>-0.1){
        position=0;
    }
    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
    } else if (position < 1) { // [-1,1]
        if (position == 0) {
            //you are centered
            for(int i=0;i<myRecyclerView.getChildCount();i++){
                myRecyclerView.getChildAt(i).setRotationY(0);
                myRecyclerView.getChildAt(i).setRotationX(0);
            }
        } else if (position < -0.5) {
            //left
            for(int i=0;i<myRecyclerView.getChildCount();i++){
                myRecyclerView.getChildAt(i).setRotationY((float) (-90*((position+0.5)*2) ));
            }
        } else if (position > 0.5)  {
            //right
            for(int i=0;i<myRecyclerView.getChildCount();i++){
                myRecyclerView.getChildAt(i).setRotationY((float) (-90*((position-0.5)*2)));
            }
        }
    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
    }
}
}
```

By the way, the best is to have a look at the project.
Thanks for those who will have a look.